# Django não renderiza arquivos estáticos que estão em subpastas dentro de /static/

Tags: python, django, static

Eu estou trabalhando num projeto Django que possui arquivos estáticos (css/js/imgs) conforme a seguinte estrutura:

**File Structure**

```
django_project
    |
    +apps
    |
    +django_project
        |
        +media
        |
        +static
            |
            +admin (múltiplas pastas e subpastas, PROBLEMA)
            |
            +css (apenas arquivos, sem problemas)
            |
            +imgs (apenas arquivos, sem problemas)
            |
            js (apenas arquivos, sem problemas)
```

Quando em desenvolvimento, os arquivos funcionam muito bem, todos. Porém, em produção, estou tendo problemas em renderizar os arquivos que estão dentro da pasta (e suas subpastas) admin. Quando vejo o inspetor do google chrome, vejo que retorna um erro 404 para esses arquivos.

Não sei o que está ocorrendo, porém imagino ser algo relacionado as urlpatterns.

Segue meus arquivos settings.py e urls.py:

**settings.py**

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
#DEBUG = True
DEBUG = False



ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 5242880

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ''

MAIL_SNAKE_API_KEY = ''

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/app/'

ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE = 8

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crm',
    'blog',
    'vagas',
    'tinymce',
    'bootstrap3',
    'django_filters',
    'cadastros',
    'projetos',
    'comercial',
    'endless_pagination',
    'easy_pdf',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'projetos.context_processors.UserInfo',

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "advanced",
    'mode': "textareas",


}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Fortaleza'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_project', 'static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'



MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_project', "media")

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

**urls.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from comercial.views import Proposta, GetPerson, GetPreco, TestePdf
from cadastros.views import EditarProfile
from crm.views import Index, AjaxCotacao, Politica, LeadGen, Pipe, SendEmail, Restrito, PessoasView, CotacoesView
from projetos.views import Jobs, AppDashboard, Arquivo, AddBriefing, Teste, Upload, Timeline, Aprovar
from blog.views import Blog, PostDetail
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDetail, name='PostDetail'),
    url(r'^blog/$', Index),
    url(r'^politica-de-privacidade/$', Politica),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url(r'^ajax/create_cot/$', AjaxCotacao),
    url(r'^crm/pipe/$', Pipe),
    url(r'^teste/$', SendEmail),
    url(r'^app/$', AppDashboard),
    url(r'^app/teste/$', Teste),

    #cadastros 

    url(r'^app/profile/edit/$', EditarProfile),

    #login
    url(r'^app/login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^app/logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),

    #comercial 
    url(r'^app/comercial/$', Proposta),
    url(r'^app/comercial/getperson/$', GetPerson),
    url(r'^app/comercial/getpreco/$', GetPreco),
    url(r'^app/comercial/testepdf/$', TestePdf),

    #pecas
    url(r'^app/pecas/$', Jobs),
    url(r'^app/pecas/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', AddBriefing, name='AddBriefing'),
    url(r'^app/pecas/arquivo/$', Arquivo),
    url(r'^app/pecas/(?P<pk>\d+)/upload/$', Upload, name='Upload'),
    url(r'^app/pecas/(?P<pk>\d+)/timeline/$', Timeline, name='Timeline'),
    url(r'^app/pecas/(?P<pk>\d+)/timeline/aprovar/$', Aprovar, name='Aprovar'),
    url(r'^restrito/$', Restrito),
    url(r'^restrito/pessoas/$', PessoasView),
    url(r'^restrito/comercial/cotacoes/$', CotacoesView),
    url(r'^b1c7879958231cf38ba31c55a46934eef7aa1c502fbffb6c71/$', LeadGen),
    url(r'', Index),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow em Português!  Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. O idioma oficial usado aqui é o Português, você poderia traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Olá ! Perdão, não me dei conta que estava no stack br :) Já traduzi..

Comment: Pergunta reaberta!

Answer (score 1):

Aquivos estáticos só são servidos automaticamente pelo próprio Django no ambiente de desenvolvimento.

No ambiente de produção, você deve configurar seu Web server de front-end para servir os arquivos estáticos automaticamente, sem passar pelo Django e outras aplicações relacionadas ao ambiente de Python (como servidores WSGI).

Há várias formas de se fazer isso - desde configurar diretamente a pasta `static` do seu projeto para ser servida em uma URL específica (que deve ser a mesma URL relativa que funcionava no ambiente de desenvolvimento), até um script para copiar os arquivos estáticos para um outro servidor, de onde serão servidos.

Aqui tem a documentação oficial do Django sobre isso:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: Opa! Sim, meu webserver já está configurado para isso ! Vou tentar ser mais claro, no ambiente de desenvolvimento, tudo funciona ok. Porém, no ambiente de produção, os arquivos funcionam só na pasta raiz "static". Eu coloquei uma pasta chamada "admin" dentro dessa pasta static, e os arquivos que estão dentro dela não são servidos.. Consegui ser claro ?

Comment: Sim - ma so problema continua sendo a configuração no web-server externo. Se você usou algum script para configura-lo automaticamente, tente adicionar as sub-pastas explicitamente nessa linha da configuração: `    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_project', 'static'),` (ponha o `'static/admin'` lá, por exemplo)